# Avoiding duplicate validation on subclasses

Tags: python, oop

I have the following Python 3.6 code:

```
import abc
import math
from abc import ABC


class Shape(ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def draw(self, area):
        pass


class Square(Shape):
    def draw(self, area):
        if area < 0:
            raise ValueError('Area must be greater or equal than 0.')

        print('Square. Side length: %s' % math.sqrt(area))


class Circle(Shape):
    def draw(self, area):
        if area < 0:
            raise ValueError('Area must be greater or equal than 0.')

        print('Circle. radius: %s' % math.sqrt(area / math.pi))
```

How can I avoid repeating the same validation on every subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the base class to create a check method, that you use in the sub-classes

```
import abc
import math
from abc import ABC


class Shape(ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def draw(self, area):
        pass
    def _check_area(area):
        if area < 0:
            raise ValueError('Area must be greater or equal than 0.')


class Square(Shape):
    def draw(self, area):
        self._check_area(area)
        print('Square. Side length: %s' % math.sqrt(area))


class Circle(Shape):
    def draw(self, area):
        self._check_area(area)
        print('Circle. radius: %s' % math.sqrt(area / math.pi))
```

(I used the single underscore prefix to signal potential users that it's an internal method, not being really part of the class interface)

Or maybe even better: create a `_draw` internal method, that one will be abstract, not the `draw` method. So you can check area in `draw` and call `_draw` in the base class:

```
import abc
import math
from abc import ABC


class Shape(ABC):
    def draw(self, area):
        if area < 0:
            raise ValueError('Area must be greater or equal than 0.')
        self._draw

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _draw(self, area):
        pass


class Square(Shape):
    def _draw(self, area):
        print('Square. Side length: %s' % math.sqrt(area))


class Circle(Shape):
    def _draw(self, area):
        print('Circle. radius: %s' % math.sqrt(area / math.pi))
```

Comment: Thank you! I just edited your second solution, I think you have forgotten to remove self._check_area(area) from the subclasses. Thank you again.